# How to set datalebels formatter in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, twig

I used highcharts to show me the number of calls from database and I also want to use quote from a database to show me the percentage as a datalabel.
The problem is in highcharts y shows the number of calls and x shows the names stored in xAxis and when i call quote direkt in plotOptions:format like this format: [{{quote | raw}}], it shows all values from database in every lebel.

```
  // Create the chart
$(function() {
    var i = 0;  
    var caller = [
        { name: 'calls', data:[{{ calls }}] },
    ]

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'EASy call {{ date|date("d.m.Y") }}'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
        categories: [{{callPoint | raw}}],
    },
   plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                 format: '{y} %'
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">calls</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}</b> <br/>'
    },
        series: caller  
    });
});
```

is it possible to do something like I need in highcharts? or any Suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Example - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hc82vfk0/)**

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return this.y +' '+this.x + ' '+this.series.name;
    }
}
```

For using data values as lebel [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqsy0row/)

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
  formatter: function () { return this.series.data[0].y; }
}
```

**From Highcharts Reference**

> `this.percentage`     Stacked series and pies only. The point's
>   percentage of the total.
>
> `this.point`  The point object. The point name, if defined, is
>   available through `this.point.name`.
>
> `this.series`     The series object. The series name is available through
>   `this.series.name`.
>
> `this.total`  Stacked series only. The total value at this point's x
>   value.
>
> `this.x`  The x value.
>
> `this.y`  The y value.

Comment: Thank you so much but this is not exactly what i need.

Comment: @TonGok: you can modify `formatter: function () {` as per your wish

Comment: i know how to get x + y but , i need to get extra x from other data for the first x to be the datalebels

Comment: @TonGok: please create fiddle

Comment: You can access all points from the formatter - this.series.data - and grab whatever information you need - http://jsfiddle.net/sd6sgLu3/